# How does Animated.Component / createAnimatedComponent(Component) differ from Component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, styled-components

We are trying to figure out cause of following issue from styled-components project: https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/issues/389

There were some changes made to refs + setNativeProps that broke animation in one place, assumingly because some animated related information is not being passed down correctly.

Hence the question to understand how `createAnimatedComponent` alters initial component, whats added? What could cause animation to break if not passed down correctly?

Please provide ideas / detailed answer if you know what could be causing this issue.

**UPDATE**
Breaking change related to the issue occurred somewhere within [this file](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/compare/v1.3.0...v1.3.1#diff-8835cf55a33e0e0d79683647a6707a5fR24) for reference `innerRef` passes down `ref`, `isTag` function checks if it is a native component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> animatable components can be animated. View, Text, and Image are already provided, and you can create custom ones with createAnimatedComponent. These special components do the magic of binding the animated values to the properties, and do targeted native updates to avoid the cost of the react render and reconciliation process on every frame. They also handle cleanup on unmount so they are safe by default.

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/animated.html

Comment: The `do the magic of binding the animated values` is a bit I can't find more information about i.e. what is it binding / how etc?

Comment: Actually what the author means here is, the animation values are added to the props of the current object i.e this.props and also as per the working of react whenver some thing changes the elements are re-rendered. So, for the animated components React switches to the Native or default rendering mechanism of the browser i.e the elements are not re-rendered on every change.